# Parsing through nested tags in XML file using javascript

Tags: javascript, xml, xpath

I have an xml file with the below pattern. How can I extract the contents of the child headers (i.e. node values of F2,F2DT,Co2 under ChildHeader1, F3,F3DT,Co3 under ChildHeader2 etc.) using Xpath?

```
<Header1>
  <F1>f1text</F1>
  <F1DT>fd1text</F1DT>
  <Co1><P>ptext</P></Co1>
  <ChildHeader1>
    <F2>f2text</F2>
    <F2DT>fd2text</F2DT>
    <Co2><P>ptext</P></Co2>
  </ChildHeader1>
  <ChildHeader2>
    .
    .
    .
  </childHeader2>
    .
    .
    .
  <ChildHeadern>
    .
    .
    .
  </ChildHeadern>
</Header1>
   .
   .
   .
<Headern>
   .
   .
   .
</Headern>
```

Comment: So `ChildHeader3` has `F4,F4DT,Co4`?

Comment: Share how you tried

Comment: yes! you can use it. https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp